# Jquery get link values from data object

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, getjson

I can't for the life of me figure out how to access the values inside this object.  Any help would be much apreciated

End goal, once I can access the link, i'll iterate each and append and img tag to the dom after the images-header element.

**JS to consume json**

```
$("#stack_name").focusout(function() {
  var name = $(this).val();
  // alert(name);

  $.getJSON('/images.json?name='+ name, function(data) {
    console.log("DATA: ", data);
    // $('<p>Test</p>').appendTo('.images-header');
  });
});
```

**Console Log outputs:**

```
DATA:  
Object {data: Object}
data: Object
images: Array[4]
0: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Connecticut_in_United_States.svg/270px-Connecticut_in_United_States.svg.png"
1: "http://www.enchantedlearning.com/usa/states/connecticut/map.GIF"
2: "https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/images/0/01/Connecticut-county-map.gif"
3: "http://www.ct.gov/ecd/lib/ecd/20/14/state%2520of%2520connecticut%2520county%2520outline.jpg"
length: 4
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
 app-init.js?body=1:15
```

[image]

**/images.json?name=connecticut**

```
{
"data": {
"images": [
"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Connecticut_in_United_States.svg/270px-Connecticut_in_United_States.svg.png",
"http://www.enchantedlearning.com/usa/states/connecticut/map.GIF",
"https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/images/0/01/Connecticut-county-map.gif",
"http://www.ct.gov/ecd/lib/ecd/20/14/state%2520of%2520connecticut%2520county%2520outline.jpg"
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access images array like this, you have have to parse json string using [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

```
img1 = jsonObj.data.Images[0];
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/XQ82J/)**

You can iterate through array using for loop

```
for(i=0; i < jsonObj.data.images.length; i++)
{
    alert(jsonObj.data.images[i]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  Couldnt get this to work.   I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Data is not defined"  with the first one and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" for the second

Comment: added an ex route that's being consumed

Comment: @jahrichie, I have updated my answer with live demo, I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8wXkV/1/)

```
$("#stack_name").focusout(function() 
{
  var name = $(this).val();

  $.getJSON('/images.json?name='+ name, function(data) 
  {
    var images = data.data.images;
    var $header = $('.images-header');

    for(var index in images )
    {
      var $image = $('<img><img/>'); 
      var link = images[index];

      $image.attr("src", link);
      $header.append($image);
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for re, this didn't do anything or give any errors. weird/

Comment: @jahrichie Please look at demo.