# get string of values of certain property from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I'm trying to get a string of ISBNs from a Google Books bookshelf via their API. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/AbuCS/) my attempt that isn't working. (I'm trying to use [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17775176).)

```
$.getJSON("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/users/115939388709512616120/bookshelves/1004/volumes?key=MYAPIKEY", function (data) {
console.log(data);

var allIsbns = [];

for (i = 0; i < data.items.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier.length; i++) {
allIsbns.push(data.items.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier[i]);
}

alert(allIsbns);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbuCS/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the object logged, `data.items` is an array (of length `data.totalItems` it seems). Furthermore, `industryIdentifiers[0].identifier` seems to be a string, and *not* an array. Therefore I think you wanted to loop through `data.items` instead.

Also it may be worth noting you probably should not be going by explicit index on `industryIdentifiers` unless the the spec calls out a predefined order. I would recommend finding the identifier with `type === "ISBN_10"`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers.length; j++) {
        if (data.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[j].type === "ISBN_10")        
            allIsbns.push(data.items[i].volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[j].identifier);
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I look for type === "ISBN_10" ?

Comment: The naive way would be to loop through `industryIdentifiers` until you get one that matches

Comment: ok I have my fiddle working at http://jsfiddle.net/nathanbweb/AbuCS/2 . i'd still be interested in how to find the type in a loop if I could get an example or snippet..

Comment: I've added a snippet you can base your code off of and a working update at http://jsfiddle.net/AbuCS/4/